# Update user email without email confirmation via Apex

Tags: apex, email, user, user-management

I have been trying to update the user email via scheduled apex, but it seems I am out of luck!

```
User u = [Select Id, email from user where email = 'emailOne@domain.com.invalid' limit 1];
u.isactive = false;
update u;
u.email = 'emailTwo@domain.com';
u.isactive = true;
Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
database.update(u, dlo);
```

Above is just one of the many ways I have been trying but its not working. It sends a confirmation mail to the new email and waits for it to accept.

I have done my research and found out that previous attempts were not successful by many fellow developers. I am posting this question just to check if there is any new breakthrough or ideas that I can try.

Thanks and be safe!

References

- [Generate new password and notify user immediately](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220459/generate-new-password-and-notify-user-immediately)
- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kJO4IAM

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/77394/2602 and https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324664&type=1&mode=1

Comment: @cropredy, Thanks but those 2 links talks about manually changing the email. I am looking for an apex or API solution to process bulk data.

Comment: If your task is one time, you could follow the procedure in the Help article.

Comment: This functionality would be extremely useful when refreshing sandboxes and having an automated means to enable all/specific users to log in. I would be very interested to hear if you managed to come right with this.

Comment: please let me know if you find any solution works for you?